# Is it possible to change the subdomain on a free Firebase app?

Tags: firebase

For example, I have set up a free developer account and have my database on the url:

```
example-name-123.firebaseio.com
```

Is it possible to change the '`example-name-123`' piece of the url? If yes, how?

I'm aware I can always buy a domain name and host firebase on that URL but I was wondering if this was an option.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Only this solution works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305864/is-it-possible-to-change-the-subdomain-on-a-free-firebase-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any user (account) on Firebase can have up to 10 apps on a free/developer plan. Each app has a unique name and comes with database/authentication (available on `https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com`) and hosting (available on`https://<app-name>.firebaseapp.com`).

When you create a Firebase account an initial app is created for you, with a name in the format `glorious-firename-1234`. So with that app you'd have `https://glorious-firename-1234.firebaseio.com` and `https://glorious-firename-1234.firebaseapp.com`.

But you can also create your own app with a more memorable name, such as `lazytotoro`. This would lead to `https://lazytotoro.firebaseio.com` and `https://lazytotoro.firebaseapp.com`. This is available for free apps.

You only need a paid app, if you'd want to switch to `https://www.lazytotoro.com` or something like that.

Comment: Ah! I was looking for ages trying to edit my exisitng app's name. Didn't realsie you could specify when you create one. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hey, I just tried this today and I got https://project-8713056029830955794.firebaseio.com/ and firebaseapp.com/
Did something change in the new console? Are we no longer allowed to create subdomains under firebaseapp.com and firebaseio.com?

Comment: Alright, but once I created an app, can I change its Hosting subdomain? I could rename the project via *Project settings*, but the Hosting subdomain remained unchanged.

Comment: The submain under `firebaseapp.com` and `firebaseio.com` are fixed to be the same as your project name, they cannot be changed. If you want a certain subdomain, you should try to create a project with *that* name. If that's not allowed, you can't get that subdomain (anymore). You can always associate your own domain the a project though, and subdomains under that. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Answer (score 7):

Once a project is created, you can't edit its `project-id`. The `project-id` is the default site name of hosting. To get different site name:

1. You can set another name than that of provided by firebase console ***at project creation time***.
   So, you can edit the suggested project name, for eg, `example-name-123.firebaseio.com`
   to like `my-web-app.firebaseio.com`
2. One project can have multiple sites. Go to
   [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{your-project-id}/hosting/sites](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/%7Byour-project-id%7D/hosting/sites)  and click `Add Another Site.` You can give a new name to your new site (even if you can't edit name of existing!)
   You can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites?authuser=0) for more

Now, Firebase launched web.app domains for all of the sites hosted on Firebase Hosting your site can also be accessed via `my-web-app.web.app` in addition to `my-web-app.firebaseio.com`

Comment: I had the same need as OP, and this was the best solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: seems that they have now abandoned *.web.dev in favour of *.web.app for newly created projects