# Firebase deployment to custom subdomain (not project ID)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to deploy my react app.

The project Id is for example **'myapp-2021'**. I created a hosting for **'myapp.web.app'**.

But when I deploy the app it automatically gets hosted on 'myapp-2021.web.app', which is the project ID.

How can i change the deployment to the other subdomain?

Comment: Read both answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305864/is-it-possible-to-change-the-subdomain-on-a-free-firebase-app), let me know if they help

Comment: I know that it's possible to create multiple hosting sites for one project. Thats what I've done.

But how do I configure the deployment in the VS Code terminal to target that specific site 'my-custom-name.web.app' and not the standard 'project-id.web.app' ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `myapp.web.app` and `myapp-2021.web.app` are separate Firebase projects. In fact, these are the *main* domains of Firebase projects `myapp` and `myapp-2021`. While you can have multiple **sub**domains on a single Firebase project, they can only point to a single main domain.

If you want to deploy to a different project, you can pass it as the `-P myapp` option to `firebase deploy`.